# Imprimir la fila y columna del valor del array en una posición python

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

Tengo un array del que extraigo 15 elementos aleatoriamente. ¿Cómo consigo que muestre en pantalla la fila y columna de cada uno de los valores que ha extraído?

Os pongo el código:

```
arr=np.random.randint(100,500,(20,20))
arr4=arr.ravel()
arr5=np.random.choice(arr4,15)
print(arr5)
```

Consigo imprimir el array con los 15 elementos aleatorios del anterior array pero no las posiciones (fila y columna) de cada uno de esos valores.

Ejemplo si fuese un array 5x5:
1 2 3 4 5
6 7 8 9 10
11 12 13 14 15
16 17 18 19 20

2 (0,1)
9 (1,3)

Eso sería. Gracias.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A lo mejor es más sencillo que generes al azar 15 parejas de enteros y los uses como índices para seleccionar un elemento en `arr`.

Es decir:

```
import numpy as np
arr=np.random.randint(100,500,(20,20))

for i in range(15):
  fil = np.random.randint(0, arr.shape[0])
  col = np.random.randint(0, arr.shape[1])
  print("{} ({}, {}) ".format(arr[fil,col], fil, col), end="")
print()
```

Esto imprimiría lo siguiente, que si no me equivoco es lo que pedías:

```
332 (16, 12) 132 (15, 0) 466 (6, 13) 328 (16, 8) 109 (18, 6) 460 (15, 4)
258 (12, 16) 192 (12, 9) 434 (14, 17) 213 (17, 7) 267 (4, 6) 435 (18, 2)
311 (19, 17) 247 (11, 5) 237 (1, 2)
```

Comment: Muchas gracias. Hace exactamente lo que pedía. La acepto como respuesta válida.

Answer (score 1):

Necesitamos construir una lista de indices (fila, columna) aleatoria.

Para la fila usamos `range(20)` para generar los indices de 0 a 19 y luego los permutamos aleatoriamente con `np.random.permutation`. De ahi extraemos los 15 primeros elementos, lo que da una lista aleatoria de filas.

Para las columnas hacemos lo mismo y tenemos:

```
filas = np.random.permutation(range(20))[:15]
columnas = np.random.permutation(range(20))[:15]
```

Usamos `zip` para unir los dos arreglos en una lista de tuplas, generando una lista de 15 coordenadas sin repeticiones. Luego iteramos sobre la lista para extraer los valores de la matriz original:

```
import numpy as np

arr=np.random.randint(100,500,(20,20))
filas = np.random.permutation(range(20))[:15]
columnas = np.random.permutation(range(20))[:15]
for idx in zip(filas, columnas):
    print(arr[idx], idx)
```

produce

```
177 (9, 12)
415 (3, 13)
479 (17, 15)
438 (13, 5)
326 (8, 7)
327 (0, 0)
159 (16, 19)
320 (19, 2)
157 (18, 18)
293 (11, 1)
209 (12, 14)
451 (14, 3)
367 (2, 9)
456 (5, 16)
420 (10, 10)
```

Comment: Perfecto. Muchas gracias. Consigue lo que pedía y todo muy ordenadito, aunque validé la primera por estar antes.

Answer (score 0):

He añadido el **bucle for** para buscar la fila y columna para cada valor. Si el numero esta repetido salen varios valores para la fila y columna.

```
import numpy as np
arr=np.random.randint(100,500,(20,20))
arr4=arr.ravel()
print(arr4)
arr5=np.random.choice(arr4,15)
print(arr5)
for i in arr5:
    position=np.where(arr==i)
    print(i,'filas',position[0],'columnas',position[1])
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, aunque no hace exactamente lo solicitado, me sirvió para ver otros procedimientos.